# Pre-populate form field with the text from a <p> using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, onclick, dom-events

I have this on a page:

```
<p class="test" style="width: 300px" title="intro">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
```

Underneath, I want to have a hidden field... On clicking on the submit button, I would like the text from `<p>` with class "test" to pre-fill the hidden field.

Is this possible?

UPDATE

Have done this.. but:

1. When the page loads, I get a popup with the contents of the field. Can this be stopped?
2. I have the content in the `<p>` changing... can we also make the field 'update' when the content changes?

Comment: It is. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Is it possible to add an ID to the `<p>` to make this 50x simpler?

Comment: Yes i can ID if that will make it easier!

Comment: @DC_ I strongly recommend the OP to use jQuery. From my own experience when one doesn't include jQuery and writes too much script, the script becomes much bigger then it would be with jQuery. And there are a lot of browser bugs that are already dealt with in this lib.

Comment: @Oybek I completely agree but sometimes it isn't possible (I've worked with clients who absolutely won't allow me to use jQuery for their site).

Comment: i am already using jQuery on the page, so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @DC_ I also had a boss who imposed not to use jQuery in order to decrease the page size. Now I teach him JavaScript/jQuery every Saturday. )) Prohibiting jQuery doesn't make much sense.

Comment: What 'field'? A `textarea` or text `input`? And do you want all of the text from the `p` in that `input`, or just the first few words?

Comment: @ David, doesn't really matter too much... it can be text field or input field, as long as the content copies. The entire p contents, not just a few words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your p doesn't change why don't you use simple jQuery assignment on document ready?

```
$(function() {
  $("#MyInput").val($("#TargetP").text());
  alert($("#MyInput").val());
});
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/oyezec/3/edit)

Comment: Just two things though:

1) When the page loads, i get a popup with the contents of the filed. Can this be stopped?

2) I have the content in the < p > changinging... can we also make the field 'update' when the content changes?

Comment: 1: Remove the `alert()` line. 2: that depends entirely on how the `p` is updated (yes: it's definitely possible, but *how* might vary). Please consider posting a second question (but first check that there's no questions existing already that might answer this).

Comment: Thank you. I looked at the code and figured out the alert. Well the <p> is changed using jQuery edit in place... so i need to figure out how to get the field to fill/or re-fill itself everytime the content is changed. Will post another question. thanks.